# And operation on hexadecimal strings

Tags: c#, .net

I have two Hex strings of length 8 digits. How to do `&` operation on these two and get result in Hex:

```
40003019 & FE000000 => 40000000
```

I have tried converting Hex string to byte array and doing individual
byte & byte which result in byte, in which case I am getting 4 bytes individually. I am looking for direct Hex result.

How can I do this?

```
var byteResult = new byte[4];
var byteArray1 = StringToByteArray("40003019");
var byteArray2 = StringToByteArray("FE000000");
for(int i = 0 ; i< 4; i++)
{
   byteResult[i] = (byte)(byteArray1[i]  & byteArray1[i]);
}

public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried?

Comment: Sounds like you should parse each string, perform the bitwise &, then format the result...

Comment: I have tried converting hex string into byte array of length 4 and doing individual byte & operation and result in byte. But I am looking for direct Hex & operation.

Comment: Here is another method : UInt32 a = UInt32.Parse("40003019", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            UInt32 b = UInt32.Parse("FE000000", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            Console.WriteLine((a & b).ToString("x8"));
            Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert (to integer), Compute (bitwise and - `&`), Convert (back to string):

```
  string left = "40003019";
  string right = "FE000000";

  string result = 
    (Convert.ToUInt32(left, 16) & Convert.ToUInt32(right, 16)).ToString("X8");
```

In general case (long strings which can be beoynd `UInt64` range)

```
private static int CharToByte(char value) {
  if (value >= '0' && value <= '9')
    return value - '0';
  else if (value >= 'a' && value <= 'f')
    return value - 'a' + 10;
  else if (value >= 'A' && value <= 'F')
    return value - 'A' + 10;
  else
    return -1;
}

private static string BitwiseAnd(String left, String right) {
  // left and right can have different lengths
  int n = Math.Min(left.Length, right.Length);

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int v = CharToByte(left[left.Length - n + i]) & 
            CharToByte(right[right.Length - n + i]);

    sb.Append(v.ToString("X1"));
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}

...

string left = "40003019";
string right = "FE000000";

string result = BitwiseAnd(left, right);
```

Comment: OMG - this is too deep :)